# Unable to install netifaces

Tags: python, pip

I'm coding a python program. I have to use `netifaces` but i can't install it. When I do `pip install netifaces` on CMD, it gets an error:

```
C:\Users\thema>pip install netifaces-0.10.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
WARNING: Requirement 'netifaces-0.10.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\thema\netifaces-0.10.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\thema\\netifaces-0.10.9-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl'

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\thema\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: as i can see your version is 3.9 so as per your system you can download wheel file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#netifaces)

Comment: I isntalled the .whl file, and i run pip install netifaces-0.10.9-cp39-cp39m-win_amd64.whl.
But it says : netifaces-0.10.9-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
Something to do?

Comment: your python version is 3.9??

Comment: Yes, it's Python 3.9.4 version, so I don't know why is this happenning.

Comment: can you edit your post and show  full error traceback with pip command

Comment: Ok, im editing it

Comment: give full path where you have download that file